# HTML Flip Card with CSS3 transitions

Tags: html, css

I've create an HTML flip card:

```
<div id="services_card" class="shadow iOS">
    <div class="front face">
        <i class="fa fa-apple fa-4x"></i> <p>iOS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
        <i class="fa fa-apple fa-4x"></i> <p>iOS</p>
        <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
        <p>Any content can go here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I have a browser compatibility problem with the transform rotate.
On chrome is working good, but in Safari or Firefox is working bad.

Here a [jsfiddle to see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/2kpkueus/).

Comment: In my Firefox works fine. Version is 40.0.3

Comment: Testing with Firefox Developer version: 41.0a2 (2015-07-20) it display 
class: front face, and back face togheter. With Safari Version 8.0.6 (10600.6.3) display correctly and after 1 sec disappear the back face div class.

Comment: Works in Safari 8.0.8 but the white text disappears when the flip is complete.

Comment: Any suggestion for a fix?

Comment: Yeah. Use jQuery instead. Here is a nice example http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: Another test on chrome 37 show same bug of Safari 8.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found a solution rewriting all the CSS and HTML code, now I don't see anymore the problem on Safari and Firefox. Any one can give me a feedback?

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="front iOS face">
        <p>iOS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back iOS face">
        <p>iOS</p>
        <p>Some text just for test </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here a [JSFiddle of the new fixed code](https://jsfiddle.net/2kpkueus/6/).